# Is there a way to bypass charge a 2019 MacBook Pro?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, battery, power-management

Bypass charging powers the computer but it doesn't charge nor discharge the battery.

Can I bypass charge on a 2019 MacBook Pro?

Answer (score 2):

No.  Unless you disconnect the battery from the logic board, the battery is going to be charged (managed, actually) by the SMC on the logic board.

Apple enables battery health management by default, so the need for bypass is lessened greatly.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211094

You can opt out of this chemical aging countermeasure if needed, and even then Apple won’t apply charge to a mostly full battery so bypass happens automatically when mostly full.