# How do I bypass the battery using command keys on MacBook Pro 2017

Tags: mac, battery

How do I bypass the battery using command keys on MacBook Pro 2017 which has a non-removable battery to run only on power cable?

Comment: You can't, because the power cable charges the battery, the battery powers the laptop. The power cable does not power the laptop directly.

Comment: When attempting several ways to boot the laptop up I seemed to have stumbled across a way that I now recognize as the same behaviour in the earlier versions. The fans were at very high speeds and I couldn't see the battery status bar. The laptop was purely running from the AC mains from the look of things. But not sure what I did to trigger that mode.

Comment: @Jim - if your fans were spinning perhaps you did this https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204463

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear why the command keys are specified as the mechanism to disable/bypass the battery - there are many features and functions on your Mac that aren't implemented with the command keys or any of the modifier keys for that matter.  For instance you can hold <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to switch languages or hold a letter to get it's dialects (i.e. press and hold <kbd>U</kbd> for ü as in Über)

That said, command keys or not, you cannot bypass the battery to only run on AC; period.  This core question has been asked already:

- [Force USB C MacBook to run off AC power](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/386580/119271)
- [Is there a way to bypass charge a 2019 MacBook Pro?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/402743/119271)

It basically comes down to how the MacBook was engineered - since the battery is no longer removable, it *must* be managed by the system and in response to market demand, Apple has implemented further management with Battery Health Management.  Additionally, to get the full performance of your MacBook, it will utilize *both* power from the mains and the battery.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to bypass the battery by using command keys, or any other software activated way on a MacBook Pro. The battery will always be part of the pathway.